# Is there an R function that lets me split and reorganize a data frame using pattern matching?

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Subject_ID| Burn_L |Burn_R |
1         |  23    | 17    |
2         |  5     | 28    |
```

And I need the dataframe to take this structure

```
Subject_ID| Side   |Burn_Radius|
1         | L_Side | 23
1         | R_Side | 17
2         | L_Side | 5
2         | R_side | 28
```

I tried using Tidyverse gather() but it doesn't work exactly how I need it to. Does anybody know a way for me to transform this data?

Comment: Note that tidyverse `gather` and `separate` have been superceded and replaced by the more intuitive `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.  Details at the tidyverse site: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% rename( 'L_Side' = Burn_L,'R_Side' =  Burn_R) %>% 
     pivot_longer(-Subject_ID, names_to = 'Side', values_to = 'Burn_Radius')
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Subject_ID Side   Burn_Radius
       <int> <chr>        <dbl>
1          1 L_Side          23
2          1 R_Side          17
3          2 L_Side           5
4          2 R_Side          28
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was missing the extra step in rename() to make this easier. Greatly applicated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? The name of the values seems to change from your input to output so I'm not totally sure.

```
> dat %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-Subject_ID, names_to="Side", values_to="Burn_Radius")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Subject_ID Side   Burn_Radius
       <int> <chr>        <int>
1          1 Burn_L          23
2          1 Burn_R          17
3          2 Burn_L           5
4          2 Burn_R          28
```